# How to solve this linear program with an exponential number of constraints?

Tags: modeling, constraint, convex-optimization

Consider the following convex program:

\begin{align*}
\min g(x) && \text{such that}
\\
f_i(x) &\geq b_1 && \text{ for } i \in 1,\ldots,n;
\\
f_i(x)+f_j(x) &\geq b_1+b_2 && \text{ for } i,j \in 1,\ldots,n;
\\
f_i(x)+f_j(x)+f_k(x) &\geq b_1+b_2+b_3 && \text{ for } i,j,k \in 1,\ldots,n;
\\
\cdots
\\
f_1(x)+\cdots+f_n(x) &\geq b_1+\cdots +b_n
\end{align*}

That is: every function $f_i$ is at least $b_1$; every pair of functions sum up to at least $b_1+b_2$; every three functions sum up to at least $b_1+b_2+b_3$; etc.
The $b_i$ are constants: $0<b_1<\cdots <b_n$.

The problem is that the number of constraints is exponential in $n$. Is there a way to attain the same outcome with a convex program of size polynomial in $n$?

Comment: You could try and add the constraints on the fly if they are violated.

Comment: @Kuifje this is a general heuristic for solving programs with many constraints. But in the worst case it might still be exponential. I am looking for a way to convert this specific program into a program of polynomial size.

Comment: True in the worst case you might end up with an exponential number of constraints. But note that it is not a heuristic as optimality is guaranteed if you do add all the necessary cuts dynamically.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For each $k\in\{1,\dots,n\}$, you want the sum of the $k$ smallest $f_i(x)$ to be at least $\sum_{j=1}^k b_j$.  Equivalently, you want the sum of the $n-k$ largest $f_i(x)$ to be at most $\sum_{i=1}^n f_i(x) - \sum_{j=1}^k b_j$.

Introduce variable $y_k$ to represent the $(n-k)$th largest $f_i(x)$ and nonnegative variable $z_{ik}$ to represent $\max(f_i(x)-y_k,0)$.  Now impose $n+n^2$ constraints
\begin{align}
(n-k)y_k + \sum_{i=1}^n z_{ik} &\le \sum_{i=1}^n f_i(x) - \sum_{j=1}^k b_j &&\text{for all $k$} \\
z_{ik} &\ge f_i(x) - y_k &&\text{for all $i$ and $k$}
\end{align}

---

Alternatively, a slightly more direct approach is to
introduce variable $y_k$ to represent the $k$th smallest $f_i(x)$ and nonnegative variable $z_{ik}$ to represent $\max(y_k-f_i(x),0)$.  Now impose $n+n^2$ constraints
\begin{align}
k y_k - \sum_{i=1}^n z_{ik} &\ge \sum_{j=1}^k b_j &&\text{for all $k$} \\
z_{ik} &\ge y_k - f_i(x) &&\text{for all $i$ and $k$}
\end{align}

Comment: This is ingenious. Thanks!